# Give each shape on HTML5 Canvas a random colour

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Trying to create a page of squares, each with a different colour. So far I have a random colour generator which works, but so far it sets every square to the same random colour each time the page loads, just trying to figure out a way to give each square a different random colour.

I've tried using functions to create a different colour but that hasn't worked very well, here is the code for my random number generator:

```
var red = Math.floor(Math.random()* 255);
var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
```

And here is the code for one of my squares (all of them have the same code, just different co-ordinates)

```
ctx.rect(820, 50,100,100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+red+","+green+"," +blue+" )";    
ctx.fill();
```

The entire code is here:

```html
<html>
<canvas id="canvas1" height="768" width="1024" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(70, 50, 100, 100);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + " )";
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.rect(220, 50, 100, 100);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + " )";
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.rect(370, 50, 100, 100);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + " )";
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.rect(520, 50, 100, 100);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + " )";
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.rect(670, 50, 100, 100);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + " )";
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.rect(820, 50, 100, 100);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + " )";
  ctx.fill();
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: In order to assess your problem I need to have a look at your entire JS code in its entirety. I am curious on how you set your colour variables

Comment: I added the entire code to the bottom of the post for you, hope it helps

Comment: `Math.random()` is only called once for each colour value (r, g and b) before you draw all of your rectangles, meaning they are the same for each rectangle below. You'd either need to reset your variables again, draw your rectangles in a loop and use the key to randamise the number, or create a function to assign the colour each time a rectangle is drawn.

Comment: That makes sense, I've been trying to do the function thing for every time the rectangle is drawn but I cant get it to work. Any ideas? Thanks anyway

Comment: I'm going to roll back your question. You must not update your question using the answers elements. And if you want to set it as "solved", please accept one of the answer by ticking it. Please take a look at my answer too, I've tried to enhance things to make the code shorter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only sets the colours once before you draw your rectangles;

```
var red = Math.floor(Math.random()* 256);
var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
```

You could create a function that does this and returns the values;

```
function getRandomColour(){
  var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

  return "rgb("+red+","+green+"," +blue+" )";  
}
```

Alternatively, you could pre-define your rectangle values in an array and loop over them to draw your rectangles. Would be less code.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


function getRandomColour(){
  var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

  return "rgb("+red+","+green+"," +blue+" )";  
}

ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColour();
ctx.fillRect(70,50,100,100);

ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColour();
ctx.fillRect(10,10,100,100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```

Comment: So i've done exactly how you said with the function, but its still creating 6 squares that are the same colour? I see you've added some more code beneath, would I need to add that or is that for the looping method (which I haven't used yet)

Comment: It was for the looping code, which I decided to abandon as it was probably out of scope for the question. It should have worked fine, can you update the code in your question so I can see what you have now?

Comment: No worries, I've updated the question. Sorry for this, its probably a very simple problem and i'm just missing something obvious

Comment: Don't worry, it's not. I've got the same issue. It looks like the Math.random isn't as random as I thought it was.

Comment: @Beltyboy118 it's because you shouldn't create the ctx.rect like this look at my answer to see how to do it

Comment: @TᴏᴍᴇʀWᴏʟʙᴇʀɢ Nice catch, wouldn't have thought it was that. It works now.

Comment: Are you talking about the ctx.fillrect or the for loop?

Comment: Got it, thank you very much! I'll update the code at the top

Comment: Shouldn't that be *256 instead of *255? As written, the code will generate a random number between 0 and 254, never generating 255.

Comment: @KenShirriff Yes, you're correct it probably should. However, that wasn't the original problem of the OP and went unnoticed.

Comment: @Lewis I've updated the code for the benefit of people who want to cut-and-paste. I hope that's okay with you.

Comment: Of course that's fine with me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to do:

```js
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    function RandColor() {
      var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
      var color = '#';
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      return color;
    }
        

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = RandColor();
        ctx.fillRect(70,50,100,100);
        ctx.fillStyle = RandColor();
        ctx.fillRect(220, 50,100,100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" />
```

you should create function for the random color (instead of creating one random color) and call it like this:

```
    ctx.fillStyle = RandColor();
    ctx.fillRect(70,50,100,100);
```

for each rect you want to create

Answer (score 0):

You must want to create functions to easily add objects, like this:

```js
// Add function to pick random rgb values
function getRandomRGB() {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}

// You may want to add this other function to simplify your code, too
function addFilledRect(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) {
  // Inside this function, we're using the ctx variable from outside
  ctx.fillStyle = getRandomRGB();       // Call the function to get a random rgv color
  ctx.fillRect(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4); // Create the filled rectangle
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Then, you can call the above function multiple times
addFilledRect(70, 50, 100, 100);
addFilledRect(220, 50, 100, 100);
addFilledRect(370, 50, 100, 100);
addFilledRect(520, 50, 100, 100);
addFilledRect(670, 50, 100, 100);
addFilledRect(820, 50, 100, 100);
```

```html
<html>
  <canvas id="canvas1" height="768" width="1024" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.